# Drawing a value from a normal distribution in F#

Tags: f#, normal-distribution

How do I go about obtaining a random value drawn from a specified normal distribution in F#?

I want something similar to Python's x = numpy.random.normal(mean, standard_deviation), but in F#.

Comment: There is no built in method, but you can quite easily implement the box-muller transform - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can for example use the Math.NET Numerics library.

```
open MathNet.Numerics.Distributions

let normalDist = new Normal(mean, stddev)
normalDist.Sample()
```